# Web Api, writing headers in response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am wrtiting a web api in .net 6, I am getting data from SQL Server and returning in json format, I want to add some headers in response as well. all headers are working fine except one which contains hyphen.

```
var data = [data from database]
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
response.Headers.Add("transactionid", "working fine");
response.Headers.Add("requesttimestamp", "working fine);
response.Headers.Add("**last-modified**", "does not work");
```

I am getting this error

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

```
response.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

but same error.

I am writing a client as well and trying to add similar parameter in request header but getting a different error

> The format of value '15/10/2018 04:30:15 AM' is in correct

```
var client=new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("if-last-modified", "15/10/2018 04:30:15 AM");
```

if I remove hyphens, it works fine.

**Update**: I fixed it by changing this code

```
response.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("last-modified", lastModified);
```

and

`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("if-modified-since", "15/10/2018 04:30:15 AM");`

Comment: Can you try with HttpContext.Response?

Comment: yes it works that way but adds last-modified as "Last-Modified", can i make it all lower case? but I would prefer Request.CreateResponse method if possible

Comment: `Last-Modified` is content headers not response headers. Try using `response.Content.Headers.LastModified` to set its value...

Comment: if Last-Modified is already part of response ok header, then I want to add another last-modified with my own value.

Comment: just changed the name of the header to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding it to the response's content's headers.

```
response.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-LAST-MODIFIED", "15/10/2018 04:30:15 AM");
```

Note the use of `TryAddWithoutValidation` to avoid validation of the header, which I believe is the cause of your problems.

The same can be done for requests

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-LAST-MODIFIED", "15/10/2018 04:30:15 AM");
```